# With Xcode 4.2 remove a view from navcontroller then push a new view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a nav controller and I push a view on the screen, a settings view, but I want to remove it out of the hierarchy, so when the new viewcontroller comes onto screen and the back button is pressed it returns it to the main menu.

I tried this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
```

But the the viewController is just popped off and the new one is not presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to modify the navigationcontrollers view controller array like the following way:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
NSMutableArray *VCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[VCs removeObjectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers: VCs];
```

Maybe the animation will be broken. If this happens you should move the part with the modification of the navigationcontroller VC array to the presented VC's viewDidAppear method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that self is released as soon as you call popViewControllerAnimated:. The push call then sends a message to nil.

You could assign self.navigationController to a local variable first, and use that for pushing and popping instead.

Alternatively, and it's a bit of a hack, but before this, you could call [[self retain] autorelease] to give it an extra retain so that it won't disappear until the end of the run loop.

Comment: Note that `popViewControllerAnimated:` returns the popped controller -- it's not deallocated until that return value gets (auto)released, or under ARC goes out of scope. (You can stick that into a local variable if you like, but that won't get you access to the navigation controller, so holding onto a reference to that otherwise is still a good idea.) Also, `[[self retain] autorelease]` isn't available under ARC, and retaining self won't save your from `self.navigationController` becoming nil once self is popped from that nab controller.